# Best practice to link local git with remote github

Tags: git, github

I am in a situation where I want to adjust an extension of the Yii2 framework to my project needs.

First I have forked that repo to my Github.

In my local machine, I have run the composer and that extension is already in the `vendor` folder.

In the folder of that extension,
I have run `git init`.
Then `git remote add origin https://github.com/dadinugroho/user-management.git`
I fetched all branches using `git fetch origin`
Then, I ran `git branch -f bs4 origin/bs4`

Up to here, it looks ok, but when I tried to checkout `git checkout bs4` I got an error
`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:`

In my local machine folder (local git) I have not made any changes so it is ok and I want to override my local folder with the latest from my Github.

Any suggested steps that should I do to set up my local development machine?

I was thinking this setup would help me to adjust the changes without the need to push to Github and run `composer update`.

Btw, the folder name is different with the folder created when I do `git clone https://github.com/dadinugroho/user-management.git`

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

When you run composer to your local machine it will add files to vendor, if your git repo / checkout branch have similar files. That maybe whats preventing checkout.

Vendor files or not, you can move those files outside for now to avoid the issue.

'git reset --hard' to make sure you are sync'd

'git status' will tell you your updated files or files added by composer if any

What i do when starting a new folder is a bit different than yours.

1 create a folder for your local repo
2 $git init
3 $git remote add origin [yout url]
4 $git pull
5 $git checkout [branch name]

Comment: Thank you @xromel I think I got it. I just need to delete those files, but `.git` so I can check out the branch. I am not sure this is the best practice though. But, at least this is working for me